# Tensorflow ML problem: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I am attempting to create an agent to explore a game, and reward it for finding novel viewpoints.
I am using TensorFlow for the Machine Learning part. My code is:

```
import vgamepad as vg
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import tensorflow as tf
import pyautogui
gamepad = vg.VX360Gamepad()
images = []

def updatecontrols(inputs):
    cam = (inputs[0],inputs[1])
    walk = (inputs[2],inputs[3])
    gamepad.right_joystick_float(x_value_float=cam[0], y_value_float=cam[1])
    gamepad.left_joystick_float(x_value_float=walk[0], y_value_float=walk[1])
    gamepad.update()
size = 256
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(size, size, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4),
])
dmax = 10000000
def translate(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin
    rightSpan = rightMax - rightMin

    # Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - leftMin) / float(leftSpan)

    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
    return rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)

def get_novelty(image1):
    nov = [0]
    for image in images:
        diff = ImageChops.difference(image1, image)
        
        # Convert the difference image to grayscale
        diff = diff.convert('L')
        
        # Get the numpy array of pixel values
        diff_array = np.array(diff)
        
        # Calculate the total pixel-wise difference
        total_difference = np.sum(diff_array)
        nov.append(total_difference)
    return sum(nov)/len(nov)
# Take a screenshot and resize it to (size, size)


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()



epochs = 2000
for epoch in range(epochs):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    image = pyautogui.screenshot().resize((size, size))
    image_array = np.expand_dims(np.asarray(image), axis=0)
    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    images.append(image)
    images = images[-50:]
    updatecontrols(model.predict(image_array)[0])
    # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
    # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        nov = get_novelty(image)
        loss = tf.constant(translate(nov,0,dmax,1,0))
    # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
    # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
    # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
    # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

When I run it, I get a problem on the last line:
`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'],). Provided` grads_and_vars `is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 16) dtype=float32, numpy= ...`

I am fairly certain the problem is in the calculation of the model's loss:

```
nov = get_novelty(image)
loss = tf.constant(translate(nov,0,dmax,1,0))
```

Where I calculate the novelty and then remap it so higher variation leads to lower loss, but am unsure how to fix it. If it worked, it would not give an error.

Comment: Losses have to be implemented with TF functions, without any casts nor numpy or non-TF functions, and also, does it make sense to make the loss constant? (it does not).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy so any transformation or anything of the inputs must be done with TF functions?

Comment: That is what I just said.

Comment: just clearing it up, thank you